# include_once works in one page but not other, no errors with displaying_error on

Tags: php, html, include-once

Edit : I'm using bootstrap 
Edit : When I include bottom and footer in actualites.php ( end of file ) it works.

I am bulding a website and I want to include a content by url. So I have :

```
<?php 
  // Menu
  include_once "menu.php";
  // Content
  include_once "contenu.php";
  // Bottom
  include_once "bottom.php";
  // Footer
  include_once "footer.php";
?>
```

When I access to url domain-name/apropos , bottom.php and footer.php appears.But then I access to domain-name/actualites, bottom and footer doesn't appears.

Here is the content of the error log file :

```
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:55.832020 2016] [core:warn] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH00098: pid file D:/UwAmp/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:56.081628 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:56.097228 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1h PHP/5.4.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:56.097228 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH00456: Apache Haus VC9 Server built: Jul 15 2014 20:34:18
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:56.097228 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\UwAmp\\bin\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/UwAmp/bin/apache -f D:\\UwAmp\\bin\\apache\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:56.097228 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7276:tid 340] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7524
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release D:/UwAmp/bin/apache/conf/httpd.conf:264
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:57.033258 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7524:tid 352] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Aug 08 14:44:57.111261 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7524:tid 352] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: I guess that there is an error when you access domain-name/actualites, enable error reporting and see what is there

Comment: I have enabled by adding in php file : ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); But I don't get errors

Comment: In php_ini : display_errors = On

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @Johan I don't think because the question is not about that

Comment: check your error.log from your server and post here the error messages that you have there

Comment: I post it in the question because it's too long

Comment: I change it, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I have copied the php file, renamed it, use the copied file and now it's working even the content is the same.

I really don't understand.

Thanks to all of you.